# Get the array chunk in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Do we have any array function in PHP to get this:

Example:

```
$array[0] = array("size" => "XL", "color" => "gold");
$array[1] = array("size" => "XLL", "color" => "siver");
$array[2] = array("size" => "M", "color" => "purple");

$color = array();
foreach($arrayas $result)
{       
    $color[] = $result['color'];            
}
```

I need

```
$color[0] = "gold";
$color[1] = "silver";
$color[2] = "purple";
```

Thanks in Advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you're looking for in PHP 5.3+.

```
$color = array_reduce($array, 
    function($previous, $new) { $previous[] = $new['color'];  return $previous;} 
);
```

If you're on PHP 5.2, you can define a function elsewhere and pass it in:

```
function getColor($previous, $new) {
  $previous[] = $new['color'];
  return $previous;
}

$color = array_reduce($array, 'getColor');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check this out it works fine**

```
$color = array();
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
{      

    $color[$key] = $value['color'];            
}

print_r($color);
```

Comment: I want to skip loop with an array function if we have one in PHP. My above code works for me just want to optimize it by skipping the foreach loop.

Comment: $color[0] = "gold";
$color[1] = "silver";
$color[2] = "purple";
like that it will fetch ,in which way you want to get the results as